# Live-streaming on Android with HTML5 or an Application

Tags: android, video-streaming, html5-video, vlc, live-streaming

I want to create a live-stream by using vlc on rtp, (preferably) rtsp or http protocols and I want to play this stream with android 2.3.4 based cell phone. I have tried starting from scratch and tried to advance step by step. I have created an html5 based offline streaming page, and it worked. However, I have some trouble with live streaming issues. I have noticed that live-streaming with html5 will be painful. So, I wanted to get the stream directly from vlc.exe to the media player on the phone. However, I couldn't decide what to do because vlc for android is in development right now, and couldn't find a suitable player which allows me to enter the address of the vlc server.

What should I do? Should I continue trying on html5, or should I try to find a suitable application for rtsp streaming on android? Should I try Wowza or another service? (BTW, I don't want to mess with socket stuff on the server side.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by streaming the content from vlc on rtsp from the PC and created a very basic html page which gives only a link to the rtsp stream. Then, I clicked the link from that html page using the phone (actually I can carry out this step by simply writing the ip address of the server to the streaming player on the phone also) and it forwarded me to choose an external media player to play the content. In this step, choosing any streaming media player (RealPlayer, MX Player etc.) can be used to play this content. There we go! We have a live-streaming from PC to Android :)

Comment: can you put your application link or source code. because i am trying the same app.

Comment: I just started a stream from computer and gave the IP address of the computer to the streaming player in Android device. There is no HTML 5 involved.